# Trying to add a delay in code execution(before an alert occurs)

Tags: javascript, delay, callstack, function-calls

I'm trying to add a delay before an alert statement executes. However, an entire code block is being delayed instead of just the part after the wait(1000) function call. How do I configure this so only the code AFTER the wait function is delayed?

```js
function wait(ms) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        now = start;
    while (now - start < ms) {
      now = Date.now();
    }
}

function cardChecker(e){
    if(e.target===prevElement){
      alert('Please select another square!');
      return;
    }
    e.target.firstChild.classList.toggle('hide');
    if(cardCheckCount===1){
      moves++;
      if(moves===1){
        moveHTML.innerHTML = moves + ' move';}
        else{moveHTML.innerHTML = moves + ' moves';}
        if(e.target.innerHTML=== prevElement.innerHTML){
          wait(1000);
          prevElement='';
          cardCheckCount=0;
          moveChecker++;
          alert('Match!');
          if(moveChecker===8){
            alert('Congrats, you\'ve finished in ' + timer.getTimeValues().toString() + '!!! To play again, please press the reload button on the top right!');
            timer.stop();
            for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
              card[i].removeEventListener('click', theListener, true);}
              return;
            }
            return;
          }
          else{
            wait(1000);
            alert('No Match!');
            prevElement.firstChild.classList.toggle('hide');
            e.target.firstChild.classList.toggle('hide');
            prevElement='';
            cardCheckCount=0;

            return;
          }
        }
        prevElement = e.target;
        cardCheckCount++;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the code that you want delayed inside of a `setTimeout()` as shown below:

```js
function wait(ms) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        now = start;
    while (now - start < ms) {
      now = Date.now();
    }
}

function cardChecker(e){
    if(e.target===prevElement){
      alert('Please select another square!');
      return;
    }
    e.target.firstChild.classList.toggle('hide');
    if(cardCheckCount===1){
      moves++;
      if(moves===1){
        moveHTML.innerHTML = moves + ' move';}
        else{moveHTML.innerHTML = moves + ' moves';}
        if(e.target.innerHTML=== prevElement.innerHTML){
          wait(1000);
          prevElement='';
          cardCheckCount=0;
          moveChecker++;
          alert('Match!');
          if(moveChecker===8){
            alert('Congrats, you\'ve finished in ' + timer.getTimeValues().toString() + '!!! To play again, please press the reload button on the top right!');
            timer.stop();
            for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
              card[i].removeEventListener('click', theListener, true);}
              return;
            }
            return;
          }
          else{
            // Count to 1000 ms and then wait until all other code has finished running
            // then run the callback function.
            setTimeout(function(){
              alert('No Match!');          
            }, 1000);
            
            // This code will execute before the timer's callback function
            prevElement.firstChild.classList.toggle('hide');
            e.target.firstChild.classList.toggle('hide');
            prevElement='';
            cardCheckCount=0;  
            return;
          }
        }
        prevElement = e.target;
        cardCheckCount++;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for another function for just waiting.

Just do a `setTimeout()` in the plcae you are calling your `wait()`

```
setTimeout(() => {alert("Match!"); ... /*other code*/}, 1000)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'm assuming the reason my initial solution was not working was due to the call stack delaying execution of the entire function?

Comment: You had implemented a `wait()` function which was `synchronous` the control will only go to the next line if the previous line has finished execution, all the code after the call of `wait` will only execute if `wait` finished the execution. In case of `setTimeout`, it is treated as asynchronous execution, so the control will go to statements below `setTimeout` even if `setTimeout` has not finished itself.

Comment: @AshishRanjan Just a little correction. Everything in the JS runtime is synchronous. The `setTimeout()` function will not be started until all of the following are true: 1) the current function has completed, 2) the timer's delay has elapsed and 3) there are no other statements on the JS call stack. The timer function does not execute in parallel with the function that spawns it. In short, only the counting of the timer happens asynchronously with the main function, the timer's callback is synchronous.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Oh, didn't know in this detail. Thank you for the correction! :)